# Styling Forms with CSS

Tags: css, html, forms

I am trying to style a form on a website I am designing with CSS. I have tried to adjust the width of the labels and it doesn't change it. Here is my code:
    
    ﻿

```
<h3>Contact Form</h3>
<div>
    <label for="form1_name">Name</label>
    <input id="form1_name" name="name" type="text" required="required" />

</div>

<div>
    <label for="form1_email">Email</label>
    <input id="form1_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="you@company.com" required="required" />


</div>

<div>
    <label for="form1_email">Telephone</label>
    <input id="form1_telephone" name="telephone" type="text" />
    </div>


<div>
    <label for="form1_message">Comment</label>
    <textarea id="form1_message" name="message" cols="30" rows="4" required="required"></textarea>

</div>

<div>
    <input id="form1_submit" name="submit" value="Send" type="submit" /><input type="hidden" name="cms-form" value="Y29udGFjdDpwZXJjaF9mb3JtczovdGVtcGxhdGVzL2NvbnRlbnQvY29udGFjdC5odG1s" />
</div>


</form></div>
```

Here is my css:
    #contact label {
    width:200px !important;
}

Yet this doesn't change the width of my labels. What am I doing wrong? Here is a link to the page: http://ridgesideredangus.com/about.php

Comment: I do not see an element with ID `contact` in your code.  Do you?

Comment: Please select an answer if you've found one to be correct or helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
#contact label {display: inline-block; width: 200px;}
```

Labels are inline elements by default. You cannot add dimensions unless you set them to block or inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, ditch the `divs` altogether. Make your labels blocks and nest the form elements in them. Set the labels to position relative so you can position the form elements in relation to them.

**HTML**

```
<label >Name<input id="form1_name" name="name" type="text" required="required" /></label>

<label >Email<input id="form1_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="you@company.com" required="required" /></label>

<label >Telephone<input id="form1_telephone" name="telephone" type="text" /></label>
```

**CSS**

```
label {display:block;position:relative;padding:5px;}
label input {position:absolute; left:100px;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y5eQf/)

**HOWEVER** [some argue](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/label/for) it is preferable to explicitly relate the `label` to the `input`